# Jquery selecting inputs with adjacent asterisk

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, I'm trying to select those `inputs` that have an asterisk adjacent to them.

**HTML**

```
<form name="checkout">
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td>First Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" />*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="LastName" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
var elems = $("form[name='checkout'] :input").filter(function(index) {
               var str = $(this).parents('td').html()
               return (str.indexOf("*")!=-1)
            }).length;
```

Result of `elems` should be 1 but it's not working, i.e. the form submits in spite of a return false in the handler so can't seem to catch the error details. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var elems = $("td:contains('*') input");
```

This is selector for the input elements that you need.
elems.length will give you 1 in this case

Answer (score 0):

Ha Ha,

Missing the onReady().
Use this one,

```
$(function(){
var elems = $("form[name='checkout'] :input").filter(function(index) {
           var str = $(this).parents('td').html()
           return (str.indexOf("*")!=-1)
        }).length;

console.log(elems);
});
```

That should do. Cheers :).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use CSS :after pseudo element

```
<style>
.mandatory:after{
 content:"*";
}
</style>

<span  class="mandatroy">
  <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="">
</span>


<script>
 $("form[name='checkout'] .mandatory > :input")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier, if you added a class to the inputs which have an asterisk after them:

```
<td><input type="text" name="FirstName" class="required" />*</td>
```

Then you could select them by their class and do whatever you wish to them.

```
$("input.required").length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the explicit requirement:

```
$('input').filter(function () {
    return (this.nextSibling && this.nextSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('*') > -1) || (this.previousSibling && this.previousSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('*') > -1);
}).css('border-color','#f00');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xG8AR/2/).